# automount w/ sshfs on macOS catalina

Tags: macos, macos-catalina, sshfs, automount

I am trying to setup automount of SSH endpoints using `automount` and `sshfs` on macOS Catalina. However, it is not working and I am not sure why.

1. `/etc/auto_master`

```
+auto_master        # Use directory service
#/net           -hosts      -nobrowse,hidefromfinder,nosuid
/home           auto_home   -nobrowse,hidefromfinder
/Network/Servers    -fstab
/-          -static
# custom; auto-mount wolverine (parker lab setup)
/-  auto_wolverine  -nosuid
```

2. `/etc/auto_wolverine`

```
/System/Volumes/Data/wolverine/home -fstype=sshfs,reconnect,nodev,follow_symlinks,allow_other,StrictHostKeyChecking=no,IdentityFile=IDFILE,port=PORT,ServerAliveInterval=360,ServerAliveCountMax=3 USER@HOST:/home
```

3. `/etc/sythetic.conf`

`wolverine    /System/Volumes/Data/wolverine`

I also symlinked the `sshfs` binary to `/usr/local/bin/mount_sshfs` as per one of the tutorials I saw.
However, when I try to open the target directory (after refreshing the mount), it says `No such file or directory`. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a programming question, it would be more appropriate on [su] or [apple.se].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that `automount` tries to search `mount_sshfs` inside `/sbin`. So, although you have created that symlink, it is not available for `automount`.

Since macOS Catalina, `/sbin` is mounted as a *read-only* volume, so you won't be able to create the required symlink: `/sbin/mount_sshfs -> /usr/local/bin/sshfs`. You can find more information at [Apple's support webpage](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210650).

One thing that worked for me with previous versions to macOS 10.15 Catalina was disabling [System Integrity Protection](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210650) and creating the required symlink from the Recovery OS partition. But I don't know if this stills work with Catalina.

You can find how to disable SIP in this [document](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Security/Conceptual/System_Integrity_Protection_Guide/ConfiguringSystemIntegrityProtection/ConfiguringSystemIntegrityProtection.html).

If you finally manage to create the symlink, you'll probably need to add the following daemon to enable the kernel extension for automount:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Disabled</key>
    <false/>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>sysctl</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/bin/bash</string>
        <string>-c</string>
        <string>/Library/Filesystems/osxfuse.fs/Contents/Resources/load_osxfuse; /usr/sbin/sysctl -w vfs.generic.osxfuse.tunables.allow_other=1</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Call it `load.osxfusefs.tunables.plist` and put it inside `/Library/LaunchDaemon`

You can find a very well explained guide in [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/245009/233957) from Apple StackExchange.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I should have mentioned that I did put `mount_sshfs` in `/sbin` later after disabling SIP, but that did not help either. Perhaps, it is the launchDaemon component that I'm missing.. will let you know how it goes.

Comment: Indeed, it looks like the only bit left was adding the kernel extension. That did the trick. Thanks! Now off to struggling with osxfuse bugs..